# iPhone/Android SDK , detect when in sleep/standby

Tags: android, iphone, sdk, notifications

How can I tell when my app is open and the user use the power button to shut the display, or the iPhone shuts the display on its own ?

what I need to do, is wait for an event, then  figure out if the screen is off and wake the screen with an alert.

actually, I need this to work on both the iPhone and Android versions of my app

I'll appreciate any insight for both platforms

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For iphone I think you are talking about lock state. If yes then you can use this methods

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

Comment: so how do I tell the difference between applicationWillResignActive for going to background and for just the user pressing the power button

Comment: for the application going to background you have application did enter background method.